# Hypergeometric function in Scipy giving incorrect infinities

Tags: scipy

The current hypergeometric function hyp2f1 in scipy.special cannot handle instances where the third argument is negative and the fourth argument is complex. The MATLAB counterpart seems to handle these instances without problems. Is this a bug in the scipy function?

Comment: Works for me in scipy 0.19.0: `hyp2f1(1, 1, 1, 2+1j)` returns `(-0.5+0.50000000000000011j)`.  (The exact value is `(-0.5+0.5j)`.)

Comment: My apologies. It does work for some instances, but not all. For instance: special.hyp2f1(-2,-3,-19,3.4+0.4j) seems to give infinity. Whereas, MATLAB evaluates the function to 0.1263 - 0.0786i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug indeed.

As a work around you could use [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/):

```
 >>> import mpmath as mp
 >>> complex(mp.hyp2f1(-2,-3,-19,3.4+0.4j))
 (0.12631578947368421-0.07859649122807018j)
```

which also allows other functions to have complex arguments - unlike in the current `scipy` implementation (e.g. `hyperu` or numerical integration of complex-valued functions using `quad`).